# Tippecanoe Vector Tiles overzooming not working

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles, tile-server, tippecanoe

I have created Vector tiles with Tippecanoe in mbtiles format. I am using tileserver-gl for serving the Vector tiles. Firstly I am creating 20 mbtiles separately as different layers needed different Tippecanoe options. After that I join tiles with `tile-join` feature. In tilestats of mbtiles json file I am getting  different minzoom and maxzoom for each layer. The problem is the layer became invisible after the maxzoom level, the overzooming is not working though I have assign minzoom and maxzoom in style json file. It's working if I create vectortiles with a single script by providing multiple json layer as the zoom is the same for each layers. But few of my layers need much precision level data so that I have to create maxzoom `z15` for each layer. As a result mbtiles becoming too high in size and taking a lot of time to create vector tiles.

Moreover when creating vector tiles with multiple json a lot of data lost in zoom scale 10-11. Again point layers also behaving weirdly. Such as, a single point feature is showing 5-6 times (See the attached image below).

What will be the best options for creating vector tiles with tippecanoe. Am I in the right track for establishing a self-hosted vector tiles server with Tippecanoe and Tileserver-GL?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible.

https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/688#issuecomment-448319676